# Creating a new matrix from at least 2 common rows of 3 matrices

Tags: r, matrix

I have 3 matrices named `mat1`, `mat2` and `mat3`. I want to create a new matrix from these three such that it satisfy the condition that the row name appears in at least two of them.

Say I have the following matrices as an example. I need a new matrix such that it contains row names **a, b, d, e, f** as it satisfy the condition of appearing in at least two matrices out of 3. How can I do so as a function?

```r
mat1 <- as.matrix(c(1:4))
rownames(mat1) <- c("a","b","c","d")
mat1

mat2 <- as.matrix(c(15:18))
rownames(mat2) <- c("d","e","f","g")
mat2

mat3 <- as.matrix(c(3:9))
rownames(mat3) <- c("a","b","z","x","d","e","f")
mat3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
rbind(mat1, mat2, mat3) |>
  (\(x) x[names(which(table(row.names(x)) > 1)), , drop = FALSE])()

#   [,1]
# a    1
# b    2
# d    4
# e   16
# f   17
```